# Custom Decorator Typescript Mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to create a custom class decorator, that creates an instance of a repository class, the snippet below represents the "decorator" and the "repository".

```
import UserModel, { User } from "../models/user.model";
import AbstractRepository from "./abstract.repository";
import { Document, Model } from 'mongoose'
import { injectable } from "inversify";

export function Repository(service: Document): ClassDecorator {
    return function (target: Function) {

    }
}

@Repository(User)
export class TestRepository {

}
```

and this other snippet represents my mongoose models

```
import moongose, { Document, Schema } from 'mongoose'

export interface User extends Document {
    name: String,
}

const UserSchema = new Schema<User>({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
})

export default moongose.model<User>("user", UserSchema)
```

But when I try to use my custom decorator, typescript complains about something and gives this error.

```
'User' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
```

Someone already had this issue, and can help me?

Comment: I had the same problem and I did not find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The argument of the decorator
`function Repository(service: Document) {}` is an instance of document 
but you passed a type `User`.

`@Repository(User)` should be `@Repository(new UserModel)`.

Or change the type of the argument

`function Repository(service: Model<User>) {}`
then you can call the decorator like this `@Repository(UserModel)`